# BinaryTree to JTree?

Tags: java, swing, jtree

I am trying to convert a BinaryTree which is made of Nodes into a JTree for a GUI view. I figure this is the pseudo-code I need:

```
if root == null
        set data  as root
 if data < root
        if leftNode == null
            add data to left node
        if data < leftNode
            add data to left node
        if data > leftNode
            add data to right node
 if data > root
        if rightNode == null
            add data to right node
        if data < right node
            add data to left node
        if data > right node
            add data to right node
```

Any ideas on how to actually implement this pseudo code? I know there needs to be some recursion to get this to affect all the child nodes.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Instead of traversing your tree, implement the [`TreeModel`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/tree/TreeModel.html) interface so that it fetches the tree's nodes as requested by the `JTree`. Examples may be found in [*Creating a Data Model*](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/tree.html#data).

Addendum: [`FileSystemModel`](http://www.java2s.com/Tutorial/Java/0240__Swing/JTreeDisplayingtheFileSystemHierarchyUsingtheCustomTreeModel.htm) is a related example.